# Ethereum private chain not able to addPeer

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, ethereumjs, geth-debugging

I created a private chain with my friend with exactly the same genesis block and we wanted to connect through the `admin.addPeer` method. The problem is that for some reason they are able to connect to me, i.e. after adding me they showed up in my `admin.peers`, yet when I tried at another time to add them, the method `admin.addPeer` only returned true and my admin.peers showed empty `[]`. We have tried a couple times and the same thing happened, namely that they were able to add me yet I could not add them. I am really confused about why this happened.

Here is my genesis.json file:

```
{

"config": {

"chainId": 16,

"homesteadBlock": 0,

"eip155Block": 0,

"eip158Block": 0

},

"nonce": "0x0000000000000042",

"mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

"difficulty": "0x200",

"alloc": {},

"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

"timestamp": "0x00",

"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

"gasLimit": "0xffffffff",

"alloc": {

}

}
```

My friend had the same genesis file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too, but I finally resolved it by following steps:

- Make sure that you are using latest geth version
- First of all, you both need to use same genesis file
- While starting geth, you should use -ipcdisable flag
- Use the network id which is same as chainID in genesis file

Hope this helps you :)